# Find all rational numbers $a$ and integers $b$ such that $\tan{a\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{b+2}{b}}.$

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, rational-numbers

Find all rational numbers $a$ and integers $b$ such that $\tan{a\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{b+2}{b}}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Can you explain how you'd use that result here?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Sorry, somehow mysteriously I didn't see the $\tan$ ...

Comment: @JJM: You must show your own efforts to get answer(s).

Answer (score 4):

We write $\cos2a\pi = \frac{1 - \tan^2 a\pi}{1 + \tan^2 a\pi} = -\frac 1 {b + 1}$ which is a rational number.

It is [well known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html) that this can happen only for $\frac 1{b + 1} = 0, \pm \frac 1 2, \pm 1$.